# Don't close dropdown after a single click but on doubleclick

Tags: jquery

I`m not accustomed to JQuery but have to do a project work which should include JQuery.
Now I have created a 'select' but don't want that 'select' to be closed after a simple click on an 'option'. It should close after a doubleclick. I tried to prevent the usual change-event, but this doesn't work.  Do I have to prevent another event?

```
sel = $('<select></select>').attr('id', 'mysel');
sel.bind('change',function(event){
event.preventDefault(); 

});
```

Is there a possibility??
Thanks
Ekkehard

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the jQuery `dblclick` event:
http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

it needs to be attached to whatever gets double clicked.